# python code returning error: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm following the video Practical Machine Learning Tutorial with Python Introduction (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=595&v=JcI5Vnw0b2c), following is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. 
Volume',]]
df['HL-PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - ['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Low'] * 
100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - ['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] 
* 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj .Volume']]

print(df.head)
```

The following is the error message running with Python 3.6.5:

> ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype(< 32) dtype(< U32) dtype(< U32)

I tried running with Python 2.7.14, the error message became:

> ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')

I'm a beginner in python, please help, thanks!

Comment: ['Adj. Low'] is a list, you need to add the dataframe df['Adj. Low'] and now it is a column in that dataframe. Do the same for the other versions. In other words, ['Adj. Low'] is a list with one element, a string 'Adj Low' and the df['Adj. Low'] is a variable index into your df dataframe to grab the 'Adj. Low' column

Comment: Hi thank you so much for replying so quick! I tried and it's fixed!